# Using a captured attribute in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to change the thickness of a curve based on how far it is from initial point.

But, even if I capture that length and confirm in the viewer, it is still not usable.

Below, I used "Capture Attribute" to get the length. But when I use it on the object I want to resize as a profile curve, it just fails. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

[image: Capture Attribute]

I've also tried Attribute Statistic, but it gives the same number instead of per point:

[image]

Comment: Even though there is a working answer, just a quick note on why your setups didn't work: in the first nodetree (by the way, you said you captured the length but it's the index) you get a list of values and try to plug it in the radius of a single _Curve Circle_. One circle can only have one radius. Only after it gets extruded along the curve with the _Curve to Mesh_ node there are multiple control points which can get a list of values as radius assigned to them.

Comment: The second nodetree with _Attribute Statistic_ node, _Length_ gives a cumulated length of the spline per control point. On a spline with e.g. length $l$ and $n$ points, the value at each control point with index $i$ is $l$×$i/(n-1)$, so the sum of all lengths of all points altogether is $l$×$(n/2)$. On the _Attribute Statistic_ node you used the first output, which is the _Mean_ output. The mean (average) value of a sum of values is the sum divided by the total number of values, which gives a single value as the result. This single value you get at each control point in the _Viewer_ node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'Set Curve Radius' with a 'Float Curve'.

[image]